# How to output multiple greater-than signs > (right angle brackets) with command ECHO?

Tags: batch-file

In this case I want to output `>>>` with `echo`. But there is output first:

```
Press any key to continue . . .
```

After pressing a key is output next:

```
> was unexpected at this time.
```

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

The batch file is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set en="^>"
set rip=3
set "_in="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%rip%) do set "_in=!_in!%en%"
pause
call :dequote _in
:dequote
Set _in=%_in:"=%
goto fof
:fof
echo %_in%
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the VT100 escape sequences you're using, this should do what you want:

```
@echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%i in ('"echo prompt $E | cmd"') do set "ESC=%%i"
set "en=>" & set "rip=3" & set "_in="
for /L %%i In (1,1,%rip%) Do Set "_in=!_in!%en%"

set /p term=%ESC%[95m^!_in!%ESC%[0m
echo(!term!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will try it out and say if it works.

Comment: Huh? Which VT100 sequences? Which comments? I can't find any mention of that.

Comment: @Stephan, I see the comments have been removed. It was under compo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop has no problems writing those "special characters" with the `for` metavariable. And there is no need to 'dequote' or delayed expansion (for printing). And no need to escape the `>` with the preferred `set` syntax:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "en=>"
set rip=3
set "_in="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%rip%) do set "_in=!_in!%en%"
for /F %%a in ("%_in%") do echo %%a
pause
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I really appreciated it.  The script works just in part but i am confident it's my foult... in fact as output I receive !_in!>. I copy-pasted your script without adding or removing anything. Do i need do add something to make the script work?

Comment: no, not your fault - my fault. See edit (for some reason in my working command window delayed expansion was active without explicitly activating it)

Comment: I see... I nearly felt stupid for missing something obvious. I'll leave my answer anyway, as it exactly answers the question *as asked*. (I'm sure, @Compo feels the same)

Comment: Thanks, but I must apologize becouse I didn't wrote all of the code... I assure you that I did that as I didn't knew the actual name of the script and I did not want to write something wrong and confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

To do it your way, it would be more like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "en=>"
Set "rip=3"
Set "_in="
For /L %%G In (1,1,%rip%) Do Set "_in=!_in!%en%"

Rem View any expanded variable string value.
Echo(!_in!
Pause
```